# Visual Studio Emulator for Android - connect to internet via PPPoE

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator, pppoe

I can't figure out how to connect Visual Studio Emulator to PPPoE Internet connection. I have Wireless network and WAN Miniport PPPOE connection.
When I run android emulator I'm unable to connect on PPPOE. 
Everything works if I use Wifi network without PPPoE connection, which is not option right now.

How I can configure emulator to work properly with PPPoE connection ?